# Generate proper output for student id and score and find max and min?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm working through the Programming in C book and this part was added for HW, but I'm not sure how to display these quite like the code comments suggest. Below the comments in `output()`, I used this statement `printf("%d\t%d\n", students.id, students.score);`  but I'm not getting id and score correctly. This is what I'm not sure about. So it's getting generated and later printed in main, but not quite how it's supposed to.

Then I'm not sure how to find the minimum, max and avg scores in `summary()` because they are randomly generated. Would I just look at `students[i].id and students[i].score`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct student{
    int id;
    int score;
};

struct student* allocate(){
    /*Allocate memory for ten students*/
    struct student* s = malloc(10 * sizeof(struct student));
    assert (s != 0);
    /*return the pointer*/
    return s;
}

void generate(struct student* students){
    /*Generate random ID and scores for 10 students, ID being between 1 and 10,   scores between 0 and 100*/
    int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           students[i].id = (rand()%10+1);
           students[i].score = (rand()%(100 - 0 + 1) + 0);
           printf("%d, %d\n", students[i].id, students[i].score);
   }
}

void output(struct student* students){
   /*Output information about the ten students in the format:
   ID1 Score1
              ID2 score2
              ID3 score3
              ...
              ID10 score10*/
   printf("%d\t%d\n", students.id, students.score);


}

void summary(struct student* students){
    /*Compute and print the minimum, maximum and average scores of the ten    students*/
}

void deallocate(struct student* stud){
   /*Deallocate memory from stud*/
   free(stud);
}

int main() {
   struct student* stud = NULL;
   /*call allocate*/
   stud = allocate();
   /*call generate*/
   generate(stud);
   /*call output*/
   output(stud);
   /*call summary*/
   summary(stud);
   /*call deallocate*/
   deallocate(stud);
   return 0;
}
```

An explanation on how to use `students[i].id and students[i].score` is what I really need help with because I've always had trouble using values created in one function, in another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good to me except:

```
void output(struct student* students){
    /*Output information about the ten students in the format:
          ID1 Score1
          ID2 score2
          ID3 score3
          ...
          ID10 score10*/
   printf("%d\t%d\n", students.id, students.score);
}
```

That should be:

```
void output(struct student* students){
    /*Output information about the ten students in the format:
          ID1 Score1
          ID2 score2
          ID3 score3
          ...
          ID10 score10*/
   int i;
   for ( i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
   {
      printf("%d\t%d\n", students[i].id, students[i].score);
   }
}
```

**Suggestion for improvement**

Don't hard code `10` in all the functions. Pass that as an argument.

```
struct student* allocate(int num){
   struct student* s = malloc(num * sizeof(struct student));
   assert (s != 0);
   return s;
}

void generate(struct student* students, int num){
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      students[i].id = (rand()%num+1);
      students[i].score = (rand()%(100 - 0 + 1) + 0);
      printf("%d, %d\n", students[i].id, students[i].score);
   }
}

void output(struct student* students, int num){
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      printf("%d\t%d\n", students[i].id, students[i].score);
   }
}

void summary(struct student* students, int num){
   /*Compute and print the minimum, maximum and average scores of the ten    students*/
}

void deallocate(struct student* stud){
   /*Deallocate memory from stud*/
   free(stud);
}

int main() {
   struct student* stud = NULL;

   int num = 10;
   /*call allocate*/
   stud = allocate(num);
   /*call generate*/
   generate(stud, num);
   /*call output*/
   output(stud, num);
   /*call summary*/
   summary(stud, num);
   /*call deallocate*/
   deallocate(stud);
   return 0;
}
```

This makes it easier to change the number of students from one place.

Comment: Okay, thanks. That fixes the output issue. Just out of curiosity what does `%d\%d\n` mean? I guess \n is just new line, but what about the rest? Then what would be a good way to go about the `summary` function? Thanks!

Comment: That is `"%d\t%d\n"`. The '\t' prints a TAB between the numbers.